# How to get different response type for the same request model using MediatR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mediatr

I am trying to understand how [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) works. Never used this library before. Below code is not actual production code. It is only for understanding purpose.

Lets say I have two RequestHandlers. Each handler takes `ProductModel` as request but returns different type of response.

```
public class GetOrdersHandler : IRequestHandler<ProductModel, IEnumerable<Order>>
{
    private readonly FakeDataStore _fakeDataStore;
    public GetOrdersHandler(FakeDataStore fakeDataStore)
    {
        _fakeDataStore = fakeDataStore;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Order>> Handle(ProductModel request,CancellationToken cancellationToken
    { 
        return await _fakeDataStore.GetAllOrdersForProduct(request);
    }
}


public class SaveProductHandler : IRequestHandler<ProductModel, Product>
{
    private readonly FakeDataStore _fakeDataStore;
    public SaveProductHandler(FakeDataStore fakeDataStore)
    {
        _fakeDataStore = fakeDataStore;
    }
    
    public async Task<Product> Handle(ProductModel request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 
        return await _fakeDataStore.SaveProduct(request);
    }
}
```

Then in the same controller I have two action methods

```
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    public ProductsController(IMediator mediator) => _mediator = mediator;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllOrders(ProductModel model)
    { 
       var product = await _mediator.Send(model);
       return Ok(product);
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveProduct(ProductModel model)
    { 
       var product = await _mediator.Send(model);
       return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

Based on the MediatR code this may not work. Looks like the `Send` method creates instance of handler based on Request type. It keeps dictionary of RequestType and corresponding handler.

If my assumption is correct then does that mean I will have to create unique request model for  each action method that will be using `Send` method?

Answer (score 0):

> does that mean I will have to create unique request model for each action method that will be using Send method?

Yes.

We usually create a class for each request, as well as a class for each response.

For example:

```cs
public class GetOrdersRequest : IRequest<GetOrdersResponse>
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class GetOrdersResponse
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then the handler receives the request and returns a response.

```cs
public class GetOrdersHandler : IRequestHandler<GetOrdersRequest, GetOrdersResponse>
{
    private readonly IOrdersRepository _ordersRepository;

    public GetOrdersHandler(IOrdersRepository ordersRepository)
    {
        _ordersRepository = ordersRepository;
    }

    public async Task<GetOrdersResponse> Handle(GetOrdersRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new GetOrdersResponse
        {
            Orders = await _ordersRepository.GetOrdersThatContainProduct(request.ProductId)
        }
    }
}
```